# Hide Label When input is in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, label, show-hide

I am having a form with label overlaying the input. Like in the below image

[image: Screenshot]

Below is a code example of the same.

```
<label for="edit-submitted-name--2">
Name
<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
</label>
<input id="edit-submitted-name--2" class="form-text required" type="text" maxlength="128" size="35" value="" name="submitted[name]">
```

I want to use jquery and hide the label each time a user focus on the input. Label should only be visible if the input is empty or if the input is not in focus.

```
  $("input").focus(function () {
          //hide the label corresponding to this input
     });
```

How do i select the label corresponding to this input using jquery?

**Note:** I cant change anything much in the html as its generated by a module in Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the previous element from the current element.

```
$(this).prev("label").hide();
```

and

```
$(this).prev("label").show();
```

However, this isn't the purpose of the label element.

Answer (score 5):

placeholder attribute is the right tool for this job:

```
<input id="edit-submitted-name--2" class="form-text required" type="text" maxlength="128" size="35" placeholder="Name *" name="submitted[name]">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

But don't forget that label-less input fields are bad practice. Placeholders should be treated like a hint. They are not a replacement for labels.

Comment: It is also worth noting that placeholder do not allow much styling plus you cannot make asterisks in other colour like in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Remy Bach has created Super Labels which does what you want, I would use his code, but if you're looking for something slightly different then you can use his code as a template.

https://github.com/remybach/jQuery.superLabels